# OpenCv Aruco marker is not detected when i parse the Mat directly

Tags: c++, opencv, c++11, opencv3.0, aruco

Hope you can help me out. I try to use Aruco marker for finding the corners of an Window. So added an marker to each corner. But when i tried to detected the marker they don't get found. If it take a photo with an smartphone and then try to detect the marker on the Photo it works. Here is a minimum working Code example:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string> 
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using namespace aruco;

Dictionary dictionary;
int markerSize = 200;
vector<int> ids;
vector< vector<Point2f> > corners;


Mat addMarkertoImage(const Mat image){
    Mat retImage, marker0;
    image.copyTo(retImage);
    drawMarker(dictionary, 0, markerSize, marker0, 1);

    unsigned char value;

    //Add marker to top left corner
    for(int i = 0; i<marker0.rows; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j<marker0.cols; j++){
        value = marker0.at<uchar>(i,j);
        Vec3b colorValue = Vec3b(value, value, value);
        retImage.at<Vec3b>(i,j) = colorValue;} 
 return retImage;
 }


int main(){
        Mat image, image_marker;
dictionary = getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250); 
image = imread( "bild.jpg", 1 );
image_marker = addMarkertoImage(image);
detectMarkers(image_marker, dictionary, corners, ids);
drawDetectedMarkers(image_marker, corners, ids);
    imshow("Display Image", image_marker);
  waitKey(0);
  return 0;
}
```

Any Ideas, why this does not work? But with an Photo taken by my iPhone camera is working?

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is. Can you add an image that isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meanwhile i solved the Problem on my own, the problem was the marker were to big to detected, with the default configuration. So i needed only to update the dectorparamenters and the example in the question worked.

**Edit:**
Because i was asked of the changed parameters here. I added this code snipped with the changes:

```
ImageFinder::ImageFinder() {
    //initalize dictionary with markers....
    dictionary = getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_6X6_250);
    dp = new DetectorParameters();
    dp->minDistanceToBorder = 0;
    dp->adaptiveThreshWinSizeMax = 400;
}
```

Comment: I am having the same problem. Can you please tell, which parameters you had to change? There is a long-long list in DetectorParameters...

Comment: Yeah added the code to the answer - the Important one is the `adaptiveThreshWinSizeMax` .

Comment: if by any chance you have few minutes, can you check if your code can recognize this [aruco image](https://b.radikal.ru/b20/1807/a4/ac260b536283.jpg)? I've used your settings but it did not help me.